# YouTube Data API v3/search InvalidChannelId with no channelId specified

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm making the following authenticated request:

`GET
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?forMine=true&type=video&part=snippet&maxResults=50&api_key=<api_key>&order=date`

I'm getting the following `400` response:

`{
    'error': {
        'message': 'Invalid channel.',
        'errors': [
            {
                'domain': 'youtube.search', 
                'message': 'Invalid channel.', 
                'location': 'channelId', 
                'locationType': 'parameter', 
                'reason': 'invalidChannelId'
            }
        ], 
        'code': 400
    }
}`

As you can see, I don't specify a `channelId` in the request. This works for most of the accounts that I have authenticated with, but it is failing for 1 specific account and I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with it.

Note that with the same authentication token and API key I am able to get the list of channels (https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels) without error.

I'm guessing that the error at the least could be misleading? Or maybe there is a bug? Or maybe some sort of configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have an account that is a member of an organization. You need to choose the organization, not the account itself (which didn't have a youtube channel created - hence the error).

Try going through the oauth flow in an anonymous window, it is not obvious what I mean if you are already logged in.[image]